# Apache to tomcat proxy not displaying images

Tags: image, apache, tomcat

I have an apache 2.4.6 running on a linux machine and a tomcat 7 configured on the same machine. I have also setup a proxy pass to access the java application deployed in webapps directory of tomcat7,

The issue is - When I try to access the application, using the tomcat's direct URL - servername:8081/test/test, everything loads fine; But if I try to access it using webserver URL - servername/test, it doesn't displays the images on browser.
Sorry, I am not able to post the links as I dont have reputation points :(
From apache server logs -

> 10.12.109.125 - - [28/Sep/2016:13:24:52 -0400] "GET /test/jquery/js/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1003 "severname/test/"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36"
>
> 10.12.109.125 - - [28/Sep/2016:13:24:52 -0400] "GET /test/test.css HTTP/1.1" 404 979 "servername/test/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1;
>   Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36"
>
> 10.12.109.125 - - [28/Sep/2016:13:24:52 -0400] "GET /test/images/testLogo3.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1003 "servername/test/"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36"
>
> 10.12.109.125 - - [28/Sep/2016:13:24:53 -0400] "GET /test/images/userImages/431724552455061171logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1053
>   "severname/test/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116
>   Safari/537.36"

Any clues as to what am I am missing here ?

Configuration follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.testsystems.com
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /examples ajp://test.testsystems.com:8009/examples
    ProxyPass /test/ ajp://test.testsystems.com:8009/test/test
    ProxyPassReverse /test/ ajp://test.testsystems.com:8009/test/test
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: We need to see your httpd configuration - in particular, whatever ProxyPass configuration you've got.

Comment: Thanks for the response !! Here is my httpd.conf file - 

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.testsystems.com
ProxyRequests     off
ProxyPreserveHost on

<Proxy *>
Require all granted
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /examples ajp://test.testsystems.com:8009/examples

ProxyPass /test/ ajp://test.testsystems.com:8009/test/test
ProxyPassReverse /test/ ajp://test.testsystems.com:8009/test/test

</VirtualHost>

Comment: Can anyone give a helping hand here? I am able to load tomcat's URL directly; for eg - http://test.testsystems.com:8009/test/test. But if I access it through the web server, test.testsystems.com/test/test, the images etc wont load. If I click on an image link, it would show me - HTTP Status 404 - /test/testtest

Comment: Still missing something here. (I've edited your question to add the configuration, so that it's readable.)

Are the images on the frontend, or on the ajp server?

If you inspect the returned HTML, are the image URLs correct? Can you request them directly?

Comment: Thanks @rich-bowen ! The images are on the ajp server (dir = /tcpath/webapps/test/images). If I inspect the returned html the image URL is correct. Yes, I can access the image directly through my tomcat's URL - http://test.testsystems.com:8081/test/images/incident.jpg